# For any constant $a>0$ and strictly increasing function $h$ s.t. $h(a)>0$. $P\{Y \geq a\} \leq \frac{E[h(Y)]}{h(a)} $

Tags: probability, statistics

For any constant $a>0$ and strictly increasing function $h$ s.t. $h(a)>0$. $P\{Y \geq a\} \leq \frac{E[h(Y)]}{h(a)} $

I am having trouble figuring out how to start this problem. 
I was thinking to start with 
$$P\{Y \geq a\} = 1 - P\{Y < a\} $$ and the definition of expectation on $E[h(Y)]$. But do not know how to go from there or whether this approach is right.

Comment: Integrate with respect to $P$ the pointwise inequality $$h(a)\,\mathbf 1_A\leqslant h(Y)$$ where $$A=\{Y\geqslant a\}$$

Comment: this is called markow's inequality and is well known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $Y \geq a \Longleftrightarrow h(Y) \geq h(a)$ since $h$ is increasing. Then apply Markov's inequality.